# Very famous Old Cyrillic Font

Tags: font-identification

I followed the instructions for identifying a font by myself and tried all of the sites that provide such services, but I had no success. Maybe because the font is from the Cyrillic alphabet and the only photo I have is with really bad quality.

Here is the picture i'm using:

[image: font]

This was a very famous font in Bulgaria in many logos and commercials in the  90's, but now it's not used anywhere and I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just looks like Cyrillic **Cooper Black** to me.

https://typekit.com/fonts/cooper-black

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/cooper-black/

Heavily used in the 70s and 80s.

Comment: My thought exactly.

Comment: Can't find the "A" without a crossbar, but apart from that... https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE92t.png

Comment: @Cai That's an L.